# zip->open not working. Returning 5 (read error)

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ziparchive

I am creating a WordPress plugin. I need to open a word document which is already stored on the server.

I have SQL bringing back the location and storing it as $file_loc http://localhost/pjmorris/wp-content/uploads/writingreview/admin/27-1.docx

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file_loc);

echo $res;
```

Currently, $res is returning 5 which is a read error but I can't work out why. I've got a bit further up in the code to download the document and it downloads as a docx. Is anyone able to help/advise what to try please.

Comment: Your file is .docx not a .zip

Comment: @Zaim A .docx is actually a zip file.

Comment: Don't read the file from a URL. Access it directly.

Comment: Instead the ZIP file in binary mode, make sure the first two bytes are `PK` (Phil Katz). Also check the beginning and end for raw PHP error strings that might have been caught in the writing process.